# Template argument deduction/substitution failed with Boost Hana type_c

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

I do not understand why the following simple example fails:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

template <typename _T>
static constexpr void Foo(boost::hana::type<_T>) {
}

int main() {
    Foo(boost::hana::type_c<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
[build] error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo(boost::hana::type<int>&)’
[build]    74 |     Foo(hana::type_c<int>);
[build]       |     ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] note: candidate: ‘template<class _T> constexpr void Morphy::Foo(boost::hana::type<T>)’
[build]    61 | static constexpr void Foo(hana::type<_T>) {
[build]       |                       ^~~
[build] note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
[build] note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘_T’
[build]    74 |     Foo(hana::type_c<int>);
[build]       |     ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The only way to make the above work is by making explicit the template argument of `Foo` by writing `Foo<int>(boost::hana::type_c<int>)`. **Why is the compiler unable to automatically deduce the template argument?**

Notice that the above code works if I use `boost::hana::basic_type` in place of `boost::hana::type` in the declaration of `Foo`. **Is this alternative approach correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type_c<int>` is a variable template that creates a value of  type `type<int>`. It indeed seems like `Foo` should easily deduce parameter `_T` from `type<_T>` when passing `type<int>`. However it is not possible because `type` is an alias template that refers to member of some auxiliary class and its parameter is always in non-deduced context.

```
template< typename x_Type >
struct FooImpl
{
    using Type = x_Type;
};

template< typename x_Type >
using Foo = typename FooImpl<x_Type>::Type;

template< typename x_Type > // x_Type can not be deduced
void Bar(Foo<x_Type>) {}

int main()
{
    Bar(Foo<int>{});
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27template%3C+typename+x_Type+%3E%0Astruct+FooImpl%0A%7B%0A++++using+Type+%3D+x_Type%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3C+typename+x_Type+%3E%0Ausing+Foo+%3D+typename+FooImpl%3Cx_Type%3E::Type%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3C+typename+x_Type+%3E%0Avoid+Bar(Foo%3Cx_Type%3E)+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Bar(Foo%3Cint%3E%7B%7D)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

`basic_type` works because it is an actual type of `type_c`.

Comment: Thanks! I also found this helpful explanation in the documentation of Boost Hana itself: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1basic__type.html